# Flask landing page with Shopify web store

Tags: python, flask, shopify

Is it possible to have a website where the landing page is a Flask app hosted through Heroku, connected to an online store that is hosted through Shopify?

For example, website.com is my Flask landing page. Then shop.website.com is a Shopify store selling my products.

If possible, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible, but has nothing to do with Flask.

You can set your A record of website.com to point to your Heroku server.

For the Shopify part, I am not familiar with how exactly you set this up on their site, but they have a documentation where you can learn how to set up a subdomain (e.g. shop.website.com) to use with your Shopify shop.